# SSL over non-standard port?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, port, mod-ssl

I have two different sites in one server: `a.com` and `b.com`.

If I use named virtualhost on ssl port, IE won't work.

So, I decided to use port 444 for SSL for `b.com`. However, it seems all browsers give error message:

```
Chrome: Error 107 ssl protocol error
Firefox: Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
Epiphany: SSL handshake failed
```

Umm.. I don't know why, but I do have seen some web sites can be accessed like `https://example.com:1443`.

Or did I miss something?

---

ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    NameVirtualHost *:444
    Listen 443
    Listen 444
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
    Listen 444
</IfModule>
```

b.site:

```
<VirtualHost *:444>
    ServerName  www.b.com:444
    ServerAdmin admin@b.com

    LogLevel  error
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/b_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/b_access.log combined

    DocumentRoot ...

    <Directory ...>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/b.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/b.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

CA config file to generate the certificate:

```
[ca]
default_ca              = CA_default

[CA_default]
x509_extensions         = root_ca_extensions

[req]
default_bits            = 4096
default_keyfile         = 
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
attributes              = req_attributes
prompt                  = no
x509_extensions         = v3_ca
req_extensions          = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
C     = ...
ST   = ..
O     = ...
OU   = ..
CN   = ...
emailAddress        = ca@b.com

[req_attributes]

[root_ca_extensions]
basicConstraints        = CA:true

[v3_ca]
basicConstraints        = CA:true

[v3_req]
basicConstraints        = CA:false
keyUsage                = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = b.com
DNS.2 = www.b.com
```

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200604.mbox/%3C00f201c65f2c$6b55c260$b701acac@Emmanuel%3E

Comment: Update the question with the configuration for port 444's VirtualHost block

Comment: It is likely your apache config is not correct. Perhaps the listening ports are not set right. If you post a config, we can provide better help

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

It's my mistake, I have setup `127.0.0.1 www.b.com` in the `/etc/hosts`. Then, however I change the apache config files in the remote server, my browser always resolves `www.b.com` to my localhost, where there is a broken certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the problem.. but try to remove the :444 from the ServerName line so it looks like

```
ServerName  www.b.com
```

The port isn't needed since the browser connects on that port but the host header will still be www.b.com no matter what port is used..

Comment: I've just added the port number to see if it works. So, no luck whether or not there is a port number.

Comment: generally when I see this it means the browser is talking https on a http port. Is there anything in the error log for the main server or the vhost on startup or connection?